# Datatables - format one of the columns as a currency

Tags: sorting, datatables, formatting

I have a simple table with header and I'm using a DataTables plugin for it:

```js
$('#uc-dashboard-top-customers .uc-dashboard-sortable').dataTable({
  'aaSorting': [[1, "desc"]],
  'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers'
});
```

In second column I have numerical values like `124.012, 9, 8.15, 16.5048` and so on. Now I need to order that column by numerical value, but format them as a currency, e.g `1224,21 €`. I could format the values server side, but then it will be sorted as a string by Datatables.

Is there a way to define format for specific column?

Comment: How is the table being populated?

Comment: It is generated by php, why?

Comment: If you are familiar with datatables specify the columns in the initialization and for currency use the following: 
render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2),

Comment: How exactly could I use it in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a sorting plugin like [**currency**](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/sorting/currency)? Basically it does nothing but extracting the float value out of a string, suitable for any kind of currency formats :

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
    "currency-pre": function ( a ) {
        a = (a==="-") ? 0 : a.replace( /[^\d\-\.]/g, "" );
        return parseFloat( a );
    },
    "currency-asc": function ( a, b ) {
        return a - b;
    },
    "currency-desc": function ( a, b ) {
        return b - a;
    }
} );

var table = $('#example').DataTable({
  columnDefs : [
   { targets: 0, type: 'currency' }
  ]
})
```

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/zfkcj8g2/**

A sorting plugin works regardless of how the dataTable is initialised, i.e DOM tables, JSON / array sourced or serverside.

Comment: This works, however for my older version of datatables I had to use:       "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sType": "currency", "aTargets": [ 1 ] }
      ]

Answer (score 3):

This should give you an idea of how to initialize the datatable. You will need to tweak it as necessary but it should certainly put you on the right track.

```
$('#uc-dashboard-top-customers .uc-dashboard-sortable').dataTable({
  'aaSorting': [[1, "desc"]],
  'sPaginationType': 'full_numbers',
    columns:   
        [{  
            data: "Field1",
            type: "date",
            width: "10%"
        }, {  
            data: "Field2",
            width: "10%"
        }, {  
            data: "Field3",
            type: "html",
            width: "10%"
        }, {  
            data: "Field4",
            width: "30%"
        }, {  
            data: "Field5",
            width: "10%"
        }, {  
            data: "Field6",
            render: $.fn.dataTable.render.number(",", ".", 2),
            width: "10%"
        }]
});
```

Answer (score 0):

*In case you want to format a calculated field in  datatables*

I do a lot of financial applications and like to use the 'numeral' javascript library:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/numeral.js/2.0.6/numeral.min.js"></script>
```

Here's the calculated column before formatting as currency:

```
{ 
  "data": null,                                                         
  "render": function(data,type,row) { return (data["Revenue"] - data["Expenses"]) }
}
```

Here's the calculated column formatting with the numeral library:

```
{ 
"data": null, 
 "render": function(data,type,row)
   { 
    return (numeral(data["Revenue"] - data["Expenses"]).format('$0,0.00'))
   }
}
```